# FNDB or .CFG Help

Tags: installing

Installed MikTex2.9 via Protext distribution on Windows Vista HP.
Great, pdflatex, with almost all packages, ran out of the box.
But ...
My work is set in Baskerville. So, I stored my font definition
file, t1pbv.fd (T1 coded baskerville) in MT/tex/latex/psnfss,
as it was on my other PC. Also copied the various .ttf, .map,
and .tfms in appropriate places. Then ran 'refresh FNDB'.
Sadly, running pdflatex again, the file t1pbv is not found.

There is no file named FNDB that I can examine like (the old?) LS-R?
Something else must also be updated, a .cfg?

Thanks for saving me an afternoon, Ernst

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from `psfonts.map` and friends  (the type 1 fonts databases) which were not updated. It should work if you run `updmap` from the command line. If you want to see what's happening, type updmap --verbose.  Afterwards, you can check Baskerville is mentioned in psfonts.map and the like ; these files are located (under Windows 7)  in `C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Ran UPDMAP, which accessed a million files while creating or changing more than a hundred 'cache' files in AppData, including PSFONT.MAP.
But the latter does not seem to have any reference to either .fd files or my Baskerville. 
Anyhow, the problem remains - my t1pbv.fd file is not found.
Any suggestions, Ernst

Comment: Was it a personal installation or through ProTeX? If you're in the first case, did you think of mentioning  the .map file in a personal `updmap.cfg` before runnind updmap? This file should be located in `C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config`.

Comment: @ErnstHarmse have you run the `mktexlsr` program first before `updmap`?

Comment: @tohecz; I don't know ProTeX, but since it's based on MiKTeX, isn't it the same here as `updmap` or `initexmf --mkmaps`?

Comment: `updmap` and `mktexlsr` are running independently of each other. `updmap` can't find a file if it's not indexed by `mktexlsr`.

Comment: I never used `mktexlsr`, only refreshed the FNDB and then ran `updmap` or `initexmf --mkmaps`. Do you mean `mktexlsr` actually does both? It's not even mentioned in MiKTeX documentation.